# How would I test Typescript code that uses namespaces in Node.js?

Tags: typescript, module, namespaces, mocha.js, systemjs

I'm writing some Typescript code within a framework that uses namespaces extensively.

I'd like to add some unit tests, that involves using a test runner like `mocha`, which I'd include as a module.  Because all the existing files are written with namespaces, I can't import them into my test as modules.

I can use `/// <reference path=.../>`, but the referenced classes aren't actually defined in the compiled js file.

I tried using `--outFile`, which forces me to use systemjs as the module loader.  I tried doing this, but when I run:

```
mocha --compilers ts:ts-node/register api-test.ts
```

I get the error:

```
ReferenceError: System is not defined
```

When I manually run `tsc` to compile the test code, I do see the call to `System.register` but System isn't actually imported/required in the file.

The closest example I've found is this repo: https://github.com/curran/jspm-mocha-example

It's using Babel instead of Typescript, but it seems to be able to succesfully use systemjs with mocha, and I don't see explicit code that loads the System library.

**Update:**

From @martin I tried adding the `-r systemjs` option to mocha.  This added `System` and solved the reference error.  However, the next problem is that the code generated by the Typescript compiler `tsc` ends up wrapping the test code within the module loading code.  Mocha seems unable to find the tests now.

```
System.register("tests/foo-test", ["config.js", "assert"], function (exports_1, context_1) {
    "use strict";
    var __moduleName = context_1 && context_1.id;
    var assert;
    return {
        setters: [
            function (_1) {
            },
            function (assert_1) {
                assert = assert_1;
            }
        ],
        execute: function () {
            describe('testCase', function () {
                it('type test', function () {
                    assert(false);
                });
            });
        }
    };
});
```

Comment: @martin The -r flag helps, but the Typescript compiler is now hiding the tests from mocha.

Answer (score 0):

To import such code, use the form

```
import 'path/to/namespace';
```

SystemJS can be loaded as a standard module as described in https://github.com/systemjs/systemjs#nodejs specifically

To quote the documentation:

run

```
npm install systemjs
```

and add this to the top of your test file.

```
var SystemJS = require('systemjs');

// loads './app.js' from the current directory
SystemJS.import('./app.js').then(function (m) {
  console.log(m);
});
```

If you are using jspm, specifically the beta branch

```
npm install jspm@beta
```

You can also use `jspm run module` which will automatically load, transpile, and execute the target module under NodeJS using the resolution semantics specified in the local **jspm.config.js** file.

Answer (score 0):

In TypeScript using `--outFile` let's you make a "bundle" out of all your source files which is supported only by AMD and SystemJS module formats. Usually when running tests you don't want to do this because if you want to run a single test you need to compile the entire bundle. I also don't think `mocha` can import a single module from the bundle and run only that.

Anyway `mocha` has `-r` (https://mochajs.org/#r---require-module-name) parameter that requires a `js` file before running tests. I don't know if this works directly by importing SystemJS from `node_module` directory or you need to create a "bootstrap" `js` file that just requires SystemJS so your modules can use them.